# Connecting to MySQL database java

Tags: java, mysql

I'm using some code for multi threaded MySQL system. It's working fine and will put entry's into my database in under half a second. My problem is, the rate at which my program will successfully connect and write to the database, is not great. Some of the time it will work fine and other times I'll receive this error, or similar:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 27,697 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1121)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3670)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3559)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4110)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2815)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1379)
    at MySQL.putEntry(MySQL.java:46)
    at MySQL.main(MySQL.java:105)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3119)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3570)
    ... 9 more
```

I'm really not sure why this happens? Executing too many statements from one address?? 
Anywho, here's my code:

```
private final ThreadedSQL sql;
private final DatabaseConnection connection;
private PreparedStatement statement;

public Hiscores() {
    try {
        loadConfig();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    sql = new ThreadedSQL(config);
    connection = sql.getConnectionPool().nextFree();
}

public void putEntry(final Player player) {
    try {
        statement = connection.getConnection().prepareStatement(QUERY(player));
        statement.execute();
        statement.closeOnCompletion();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The code I've not included is irrelevant, uses java.sql.Connection. Does anyone have any idea why this is occuring? Thanks.

Comment: I just wonder around this statement: prepareStatement(QUERY(player)); PreparedStatement shall be used when you have parameters to set.

Comment: Are you sure that you free up your resources after use? You need to close result set, statement and connection in this order in finally block, otherwise various strange exceptions may occur. JDBC driver will hold some data and RDBMS may hold them as well. Try to clean up correctly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting. The QUERY method is just a string and the player parameter is just for getting the name of the player and a few other fields. As for freeing up resources, I close the statement as you can see: statement.closeOnCompletion(). I didn't look into the method I just assumed that it closed it. I don't get a result set, should I be? I'm just putting data into a database, does that require a ResultSet? And finally do I have to close the connection, I wanted to keep it open and just keep executing statements through that one connection, maybe I should read documentation.Thanks

Comment: Okay so the problem is that I don't close the connection. Creating a new connection to the database every time greatly increases the time it takes to put data into the database, is there any way around it?

Comment: 1) You use kind of connection pool (I assume), so do not worry and close it, it will reuse it next time. If you keep it in object lifecycle, you never know, when garbage collector will close it. And it may even time out, so you will receive such communicatin errors.

Comment: regarding PreparedStatement - it is important to use it in web development as XSS protection. But correctly: prepareStatement("insert ... ? .."); ps.setParameter(1, value); Otherwise it makes no sense to select it, if you do not pass any parameter.

Comment: glad to hear, that its working, separated comment to answear.

Comment: Okay so, I've fixed this problem and it was because I had to close the connection but I have one more question. This works fine one it's own however, when I integrate into my server it doesn't work? When I print the stack trace it's giving me the same error as stated above. What could be causing this, it's the exact same code? I did contemplate asking a new question but I figured it's on the same subject/topic so I posted here, I wasn't sure whether it was the correct thing to do. Thanks...

Comment: are you sure that you deployed correct code?

Comment: Yes it was exactly the same code. Peculiar isn't it...

Comment: I've fixed it now anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: what was the problem?

Comment: I included a finally block where the connection and the statement are closed, as you said. Also when an SQLException is caught, I close the connection and create a new one. Seems to be working great now.

Comment: yes, this is standard JDBC pattern. I am glad that I helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You should close your statement and connection, once you are done, otherwise resource pool may be exhausted or your connection may time out. I recommend to obtain new connection from some JDBC pool. I used to use proxool few years ago in servlets environment. If you are in J2EE, then application server shall do it for you, but you have to use DataSource.